# Triangle problem with a simpler solution

Tags: geometry

> Problem: In the triangle $\mathit{ABC}$ the angle $A$ is 60°. The “interior” circle has center $O$. If $|\mathit{OB}|=8$, $|\mathit{OC}|=7$, how long is $\mathit{OA}$?

“Solution”: Let the radius be $R$. Since $A=60°$; $|\mathit{OA}|=2R$ and (see image below) $|\mathit{AD}|=|\mathit{AF}|=\sqrt{3}R$. Pythagoras’ Theorem on $\triangle\mathit{BDO}$ and $\triangle\mathit{CEO}$ gives $|\mathit{DB}|=\sqrt{64-R^2}$ and $|\mathit{CF}|=\sqrt{49-R^2}$ so we have.
\begin{align*}
b&=\sqrt{3}R+\sqrt{64-R^2}\\
c&=\sqrt{3}R+\sqrt{49-R^2}.
\end{align*}
Cosine Theorem on $\triangle\mathit{ABC}$ gives
$$
a
=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(60°)}
=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-bc}
$$
which can be expressed in terms of $R$.

[image]

Two expressions for the area (left = sinus theorem, right = interior circle radius = $2A/(a+b+c)$ where $A$ is the area) gives
$$\tfrac{1}{2}bc\sin(60°)=\tfrac{1}{2}(a+b+c)R$$
which can be expressed in terms of $R$ and gives the solution $R=28\sqrt{3}/13\approx3.73057$ using Mathematica (the equation is rather ‘complex’ to write out).

I'm not sure this correct however. Drawing it in GeoGebra does not ‘match up’ (see image above) and I think the equation is too advanced to the be correct ‘M.O.’ for this problem. Is there a better, simpler (and correct) way to solve this problem? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that,
$$
OA\sin{30^o}=7\sin{\frac{C}{2}}=8\sin{\frac{B}{2}}=r
$$
where $r$ is the radius of incircle.

So,
$$
\begin{align}
7\sin{\frac{C}{2}}&=8\sin{\frac{B}{2}} \\
&=8\cos{\frac{A+C}{2}}\\
&=8(\cos{30^o\cos{\frac{C}{2}}-\sin{30^o\sin{\frac{C}{2}}}})\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\tan{\frac{C}{2}}=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{11}
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! An excellent solution. So my first calc. was correct (although all too complex). But I seem to get the GeoGebra drawing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $|IA|=x$, $|IB|=y=8$, $|IC|=z=7$,
$|BC|=a$,
$|AC|=b$,
$|AB|=c$,
$\angle CAB=\alpha=60^\circ$,
$\angle ABC=\beta$,
$\angle BCA=\gamma$,
and denote semiperimeter, inradius and circumradius of
$\triangle ABC$ as $\rho,r$, and $R$, respectively.

\begin{align} 
\angle CIB&=
180^\circ
-\tfrac12\beta
-\tfrac12\gamma
=
180^\circ
-\tfrac12(180^\circ-\alpha)
=90^\circ+\tfrac12\alpha
=120^\circ
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

By cosine rule,

\begin{align}
\triangle IBC:\quad
a&=\sqrt{y^2+z^2-2yz\cos(120^\circ)}=
\sqrt{y^2+z^2+yz}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Note that $|IC_t|=r$ is the height of $\triangle IBC$
with the corresponding base $|BC|=a$,
so we can apply two expressions for the area:

\begin{align} 
S_{IBC}&=\tfrac12\,a\,r
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
S_{IBC}&=\tfrac12\,yz\sin(120^\circ)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}
to find the inradius

\begin{align} 
r&=\frac{\sqrt3 yz}{2\sqrt{y^2+z^2+yz}}
\tag{5}\label{5}
\end{align}

And from
$\triangle IAC_t$
we can conclude that

\begin{align} 
|IA|=x&=2r
=\frac{\sqrt3 yz}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2+yz}}
=\frac{56\sqrt3}{13}
\approx 7.46
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Comment: A fine solution.